# Why is my button disabled when I set the open dialog command?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, material-design-in-xaml

I am using [Material Desgin for WPF](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) 's `DialogHost` and when I set the command to open the dialog my button is disabled, even with the `IsEnabled="True"` property.

Here's my button XAML code:

```
<Button IsEnabled="True" Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}" TabIndex="16" x:Name="ButtonSalvar" BorderBrush="#FF2A5500" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Height="50" Margin="10 0 20 20" Background="#FF2A5500">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Check" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="0 0 10 0" />
        <TextBlock Text="Salvar" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place your button inside of your `DialogHost`, if you do not specify a `CommandTarget`.

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost>
   <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
       <!-- Your dialog content -->
   </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
   <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"
           Content="Show"/>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Alternatively, name the dialog host via `x:Name="YourDialogHost"` and set it as `CommandTarget` of your button, if it is not inside of your dialog host.

```
<Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"
        CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=YourDialogHost}"
        Content="Show"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, my button was out of DialogHost!